# What is this door mechanism called

Tags: doors, lock

I am planning to flip a door round so it opens with the hinges on the other side. Before I even start I want to know if the 'lock' mechanism exists in a mirrored format so the door can still open into the room.

I have an [photograph of the mechanism that I would like to identify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikGUG.jpg). If I can find out what the name is then I can at least start to search to see if that component exists in a mirrored format!

[image: photograph of the mechanism that I would like to identify]

Comment: I believe it has a specific name, but I don't remember it.  I have seen this type of lock in the Villa Terrace Decorative Arts Museum in Milwaukee WI.  They might be able to tell you about them https://www.villaterracemuseum.org/contact.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this kind of door lock called in English?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125870/what-is-this-kind-of-door-lock-called-in-english)

Answer (score 2):

This is a **rim lock** or sometimes called a **rim latch**. Yours looks to be made of cast iron, and while you may not be able to find the exact duplicate, you may be able to come close.

Comment: This lock may be reversible. Take it apart and reassemble the opposite way.  See http://www.houseofantiquehardware.com/small-cast-iron-rim-latch-set-with-bennington-style-knobs-and-rosette?utm_source=froog&utm_medium=cse-nc&utm_campaign=gdf&partner=froog&gdffi=acd9967c52ff4737a3a3e0a43a275a41&gdfms=B5F8BB958E5342DA9EA2095A39953BC2&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1PPJBRDqARIsABNl38Eo3eVaMbenacQnhi7EPiAKlDHS9G1zVy_z9snmEm14B1iYe4f5RigaAlm3EALw_wcB