# What is this kind of door lock called in English?

Tags: lock

Would it be called "overlap door lock"?
Instead of being installed inside the door, it is screwed outside of the door.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In English, the question should read, "**What** is this kind of door lock called?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are usually called "rim locks" in North America and the UK. Maybe different elsewhere.

Answer (score 14):

I have usually seen these just called "surface-mount locks". I have never seen "rim lock" used in the (Eastern) USA.

Comment: Even if this isn't the correct term, it's the one most likely to be understood at the hardware store.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is "rim lock": http://www.houseofantiquehardware.com/rim-lock

Answer (score 3):

In Danmark they are called "kasselås" in danish, which translates to "box lock", probably referring to it being a visible as a box mounted on the outside of the door instead of inside it.

Comment: Is "Danmark" what the Danes call their country, Denmark? Or just a typo ;-)

Comment: @Xen2050 [Fairly easy to check](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danmark).

Comment: @DanMašek Is it though? That page is in Danish, so "Danmark" is Danish  for  "Denmark"... But since we're using English here, it must be a typo *and* the Danish name for Denmark... It was easier to just ask

Comment: Yes, "Danmark" is the danish version of "Denmark". Could be a typo but it isn't. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

People in the UK often call them "Yale locks", because that is one of the most common brands. Like we usually call Vacuum cleaners "hoovers"

Comment: Yale type locks don't have the deadbolt as well, only the latch